# Kivy dynamically update MDDropDownMenu items, after changing them

Tags: drop-down-menu, kivy, kivy-language

The dropdown list updates only after window resize.
Is there a way to update it as soon as I update the recycleview which contains the search results?

```
self.menu.items = self.menu_items
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add a new function in menu.py source file, in the official docu there is only **create_menu_items(self)** method which only supports create the same number items,

add a new function **create_menu_item** such as follows

```
def create_menu_item(self,text):
    """Creates one menu item"""

    if self.items:
        data = self.items[0]
    else:
        return

    if self.use_icon_item:
        item_cls = MDMenuItemIcon
    else:
        item_cls = MDMenuItem

    item = item_cls(
        text=text,
        icon=data.get("icon", ""),
        divider=data.get("divider", "Full"),
    )
    if self.callback:
        item.bind(on_release=self.callback)

    right_content_cls = data.get("right_content_cls", None)
    # Set right content.
    if isinstance(right_content_cls, RightContent):
        item.ids._right_container.width = right_content_cls.width + dp(
            20
        )
        item.ids._right_container.padding = ("10dp", 0, 0, 0)
        item.add_widget(right_content_cls)
    else:
        if "_right_container" in item.ids:
            item.ids._right_container.width = 0
    self.menu.ids.box.add_widget(item)
```

This will allow you to immediately add a new widget with the new text and the same callback function based on the previous item in your menu